# How to get a query param from the ActivatedRoute snapshot in the app component in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, snapshot, query-string

I want to get a query param in my `app.component` synchronously, not using `ActivatedRoute`'s `queryParamMap` observable. For this reason I use the route snapshot as follows:

```
const param = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param');
```

This works in child components, but does not seem to work in the `app.component`. Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuvwpi).

What's the reason and how do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: You have not shared a link to your code.

Comment: @AmitChigadani sorry, just fixed the url. You can have a look at it now.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you are accessing the route's snapshot. Which is null at the time the app-component runs through the initialisation phase.

If your child component gets created, while the routing has already taken place, the snapshot might give you the right queryParam after navigating. But for example, if you are within a deeplink and you are trying to refresh the page, the snapshot would probably be null as well even in your child component.

To access the routeParam once its there, you would need to actually subscribe to the queryParamMap or queryParams. Something like:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(map((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      return paramMap.get('param');
    }), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(val => {
      this.param = val;
      // having changedetection.onPush activated you would need to call the 
      // cdR.markAsChecked() here
    })
```

Maybe this helps: [Angular Router: Understanding Router State](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-router-state-7b5b95a12eab)